# How can I return a value from a CakePHP list array to use in a form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, cakephp

I've been using CakePHP to develop an application and I have some basic permissions that are aimed to restrict the ability of the users and help to prevent errors.

I have a form where someone with the a certain permission or higher can create a new member of staff. One of the fields in the form allows them to associate a school to a member of staff. If they have the minimum access required I would like selection to auto-fill as the school the creator has associated with them and then if they are an admin they have the option of choosing from the selection.

In the controller I am calling this line which populates the array of schools:

```
$this->set('schools', $this->Staff->School->find('list', array('conditions' => array('School.active' => !null), 'order' => array('name' => 'ASC'))));
```

And the array looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [2]=> string(15) "School A"
  [3]=> string(15) "School B"
  [1]=> string(17) "School C"
  [6]=> string(21) "School D"
}
```

The `AuthComponent` stores the school id in the following way: `AuthComponent::user('school_id')` and for the purpose of this the value is set to `1`.

In the add view the conditions for showing the selection look like this:

```
if (AuthComponent::user('admin') == 1) {
    echo $this->Form->input('school_id', array('label' => 'School *',    'options' => array($schools), 'required' => 'required'));
} else {
    echo $this->Form->input('school_id', array('label' => 'School *', 'value' => $schools[AuthComponent::user('school_id')], 'disabled' => 'disabled'));
}
```

For some reason the disabled view defaults to showing the first school in the list. I have used `var_dump($schools[AuthComponent::user('school_id')];` which returns `String(8) => "School C"`so I am confused on why the selection will not show correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestions or an alternative solution to achieving the same outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few oddities in the code in the question:

#### Conditions

```
'conditions' => array('School.active' => !null)
```

`!null` is simply `true`, this is *identical* to using:

```
'conditions' => array('School.active' => true)
```

If you want to check for not-null the condition to use is:

```
'conditions' => array('School.active NOT' => null)
```

OR

```
'conditions' => array('NOT' => ('School.active' => null))
```

#### Options

```
'options' => array($schools)
```

`$schools` is already an array - this is creating a nested array, which will be interpreted as a select with an optGroup named "0". I.e. like this:

```
<select name="data[User][school_id]" id="UserSchoolId">
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="2">School A</option>
        <option value="3">School B</option>
        <option value="1">School C</option>
        <option value="6">School D</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

#### It's always a select

You haven't explicitly said so, but whether the user is an admin or not, the input is a select. It sounds like you're expecting a disabled text input, **always look at the html source** to verify what exactly you're looking at.

This occurs because CakePHP will automatically convert a field named `schools_id` to a select if there is a view variable named `schools`. This is also the reason why the first school is always selected irrespective of the auth'ed user's school, the code in the question is effectively:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'school_id',
    array(
        'label' => 'School *',
        'options' => $schools, // implicit
        'value' => $schools[AuthComponent::user('school_id')],
        'disabled' => 'disabled'
    )
);
```

The result is markup like this:

```
<select name="data[User][school_id]" value="School C" id="UserSchoolId">
    <option value="2">School A</option>
    <option value="3">School B</option>
    <option value="1">School C</option>
    <option value="6">School D</option>
</select>
```

There is no school with that value - so the html will act like it's not there and pick the first one.

### Solution

You'll need code equivalent to this:

```
$options = ['label' => 'School *'];
if (!AuthComponent::user('admin')) {
    $options += [
        'value' => AuthComponent::user('school_id'),
        'disabled' => 'disabled'
    ];
}
echo $this->Form->input('school_id', $options);
```

Obviously, do not rely on the form for security of any kind - a disabled input does not prevent a user editing the html, enabling it and changing the value. Either use [the security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent) (which prevents form tampering), forcefully ensure that the school_id (and any other fields that are relevant) match the auth'ed user's data in the controller action before saving/changing records or both.

Comment: Thank you very much @AD7six, I'm fairly new to CakePHP and your answer has really helped me to understand what goes on in the background. :)